# Undefined reference to several functions in libcsfml-window on Solus OS

Tags: c, codeblocks, sfml

After building CSFML from the latest sources, and setting it up in Code::Blocks, I am getting an undefined reference error when I attempt to build my project. I've linked all of the CSFML libraries in Code::Blocks. I am running the latest version of Solus Budgie and Code::Blocks.

This is the relevant error:

```
../../../../usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `sf::String::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() const'
```

Here is where the error appears to originate, as this is a c-based project and it is attempting to build using g++:

```
g++ -L/home/riley/Downloads/CSFML-2.2-linux-gcc-64-bit/CSFML-2.2/lib -o bin/Release/Asterisk obj/Release/display.o obj/Release/entity.o obj/Release/levels.o obj/Release/main.o obj/Release/map.o obj/Release/quest.o obj/Release/terrain.o  -s  /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.so /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-graphics.so /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-network.so /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-system.so /usr/local/lib/libcsfml-window.so -lsfml-graphics
```

Based on what I know, it appears that there are several functions and other things that are referenced in `libcsfml-window` that I don't have installed. How can I go about fixing this error? I'm not sure what I don't have installed, as I have all of the standard libraries installed, as well as `SFML`.

Comment: You cannot link a shared library by passing the path of the shared library file. You have to use `-L ../../../../usr/local/lib/ -l csfml-audio`, etc. And please don't ignore the warnings of the compiler, fix your code.

Comment: @Pablo I'll try that. Do I set that as a compiler flag or do something else?
I'll fix the code, I'm working on a recently-cloned repository that a friend created, so I've had no time to fix the issues.

Comment: I don't use code blocks, I have no idea how to setup additional links libraries and additional link library paths there. Check the linking settings of your project.

Comment: I have linked the libraries through Code::Blocks already, so I don't know what else to do at this point.

Comment: I cannot help you there, I don't use Code::Blocks.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Regarding whoever downvoted my question: Is there anything I could clarify/add to improve my question? I believe I've thoroughly explained my issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I downvoted because originally I saw only C code and an error about linking a C++ library, so it indicated no research. It took me a while to go through all the output (that doesn't contribute to the question) and spot where the error originated. The downvote is now locked, if you edit your question and post only the relevant g++ line and error messages, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @Pablo: I've edited my question, completely missed the g++ line in there, hopefully that gets me someplace useful.